# Getting error while trying to migrate data to Azure SQL Database from Oracle using the "SSMA for Oracle" tool

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-migration, data-migration

I am using the "SSMA for Oracle" tool to migrate Oracle databases to Azure SQL Databases. I am able to migrate the schemas. But I am getting the below error while migrating the data:

> Error occurred while inserting table information into Data Migration Auxiliary table. Reason: Invalid object name 'Databasename.WIMS_ST.o2ss.MSSsmaDmTables'

I have already followed this link and all the steps in it without any success: [Error Migrating Data Error occurred while...](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsserver/en-US/cb691d8d-68fb-4127-b2b5-b2d50254f8a5/error-migrating-data-error-occurred-while-inserting-table-information-into-data-migration-auxiliary?forum=sqlservermigration)

Has someone else also faced this issue recently? Can you please provide some pointers. Any log files etc. I should be checking or any configurations I may be missing.
"
To add more, I realized that when i select"Synchronize with database" from the Azure SQL Database Metadata explorer window, in the Synchronization error ouput, I see lots of error messages as "synchroniztion error: Invalid object name 'ssma_oracle.t_dbms_sql_recordset'. On:database.ssma_oracle.t_dbms_sql_recordset
Errors: Cannot find the object "ssma_oracle.db_error_list" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Comment: Did you follow the document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/migrating-oracle-data-into-sql-server-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver15#migrating-data-to-sql-server?

Comment: Hi Leon, yes I followed these steps. As Target is "Azure SQL Database", I don't see the migration engine settings to perform on the client or server-side. I believe it only comes if the target server is on-prem SQL server not Azure.

Comment: We are facing the same issue, but did not find the problem yet.
It could be that your user does not have the right permissions.